# bxSlider does not initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to initialize the jQuery bxSlider but for some reason, even adding the same resources as shown on the website examples I can't intialize the plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: true
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcymj0s0/2/

Comment: You need to include the scripts properly: https://jsfiddle.net/rcymj0s0/5/. See the 'external resources' tab on the left for the CDN locations I used. Note that the image is the same in both slides so nothing appears to change there. You can see it works from the pager icons at the bottom.

Comment: there is jQuery error (ReferenceError: $ is not defined) in console in your jsfiddle please check it.

Comment: The JSFiddle demonstrates my websites html structure aswell and it is not working with this set-up. Console logs 'bxSlider is not a function'

Comment: @user3615851 are you looking at my fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [this cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bxslider) path it will work.

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  captions: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css">
    
<div id="slider-section">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="http://media.voog.com/0000/0039/0203/photos/icon.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://media.voog.com/0000/0039/0203/photos/icon.png" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your own build of jQuery in `/javascripts/application.js`.  This is after you have already included jQuery earlier in the DOM and tried to add the bxSlider plugin.  To fix the issue, include the bxSlider javascript *after* the line that has the following:

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

The result will be the following (remember to remove the original bxSlider script tag before making this change)

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```